# Git Cant push or pull encountered end of file

Tags: git, github

I having problem with git on my centos linux,

When I try to push from my root account I'm getting message

> fatal: unable to access Encountered end of file

And not only master but any local branches I want to send to remote.
Looks like same thing is when I try do git fetch.

But on my user account I have no problem with it.

What can be the source of this difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can depend on the protocol use for pull/fetch.

Since the `HOME` is not the same, using ssh would mean looking for the keys and not finding them.
The global git config would also not be there.

With https, an "Encountered end of file" could also means an ssl handshake failure, where the user account is setup to use the right cipher, as opposed to the root account. (check that with `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push`)